# How to get Devops OwnerID

Tags: azure, azure-devops

In this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/account/accounts/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0 of microsft, Im wondering where can i get this ownerId?
[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the owner Id with browser.  I navigate to the Azure Devops Organization setting->Overview tab with [F12 network panel](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network/).

For more information please refer to the screenshot.

[image]